# How to have 2 divs next to each other and have one dynamically resize without dropping down

Tags: html, css

Im tryin to get two divs on a page next to each other. The one on the left has to be 100px wide and the one on the right has to take up the remainder of the page, and I want the tect in that div to wrap in it.

I have tried (HTML):

```
<div class="video">
    <div class="left">
       left stuff
    </div>
    <div class="right" >right stuff</div>
</div>
```

(CSS):

```
.video 
{
    width: 100%;  
    height:75px;
    border-bottom:Solid 1px #c9c9c9;
    position:relative;

}

.video .left 
{ 
    float:left; 
    height:74px; 
    width:116px;
}

.video .right 
{ 
    height:74px; 
    float:left; 
    position:relative; 
    width:180px;

}
```

Bu this causes the div on the right to drip to the line below. How can I get it to stay on the same line and just occupy the rest of the space that the the left div is not using?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `float` from the right div and give it a `margin-left` with the `width` of the left div.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), the background color is purely presentational, the remaining are the minimum required styles.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 1909473</title>
        <style>
            .video {
                width: 100%;  
                height: 75px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
            }

            .video .left { 
                float: left; 
                width: 116px;
                height: 74px;
                background: #fee;
            }

            .video .right { 
                margin-left: 116px;
                height: 74px;
                background: #efe;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="video">
            <div class="left">left stuff</div>
            <div class="right">right stuff</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Only ensure that you're using [strict doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), otherwise IE will go faulty.

Comment: This is gold. It fixed what I've been trying to do for an hour -__- it seems so obvious now..  thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.video {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.video .left,
.video .right { 
    display: table-cell;
}
.video .left { 
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this approach because it automatically handles the heights of the two columns.